# Windows Service Bus 1.1: looking for Powershell script to delete topic/subscription

Tags: c#, powershell, servicebus

I would like to delete SB topic and their subscription through power-shell script.

I'm able to delete using C# code which available within `Microsoft.ServiceBus` namespace and `NamespaceManager` class.

```
public void DeleteSubscription(string topicPath, string name);
```

But looking for power-shell script?

[image]

I got below script which delete entire SB namespace.

```
Remove-SBNamespace –Name 'ServiceBusDefaultNamespace' -Force
```

[image]

Please suggest script which can delete individual Topic and their subscription. Thanks!

**I thought to use some Azure version command, here is update,**

I m using command `Remove-AzureRmServiceBusTopic -NamespaceName SB-Example1 -TopicName SB-Topic_exampl1`, it's is asking for `-ResourceGroup`. Now for on prem Service Bus I don't think we can pass any `ResourceGroup, please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login using the appropriate method and Select your desired Subscription and ResourceGroup and then proceed with the SB cmdlet.

## Login-Subscription-ResourceGroup for powerShell

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Login with your Azure Account"
Add-AzureRmAccount
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Your available Subscriptions"
Get-AzureRmSubscription | Format-List -Property Name, Id
$subscriptions = @(Get-AzureRmSubscription | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id)
$flag = $true
while ($flag) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Enter target Subscription Id: ' -NoNewline
    $subscriptionId = Read-Host
    if ($subscriptions -contains $subscriptionId) {
        Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
        Write-Output "yes"
        $flag = $false
        break
    }
    elseif ($flag -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "Enter valid Subscription Id"
    }
}
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow `r`n'Your Available Resource Groups'
    Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName
    $resourceGroups = @(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName)
    $flag = $true
    while ($flag) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green `r`n'Enter target Resource Group name: ' -NoNewline
        $resourceGroupName = Read-Host
        if ($resourceGroups -contains $resourceGroupName) {
            Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Tag @{}
            $flag = $false
            break
        }
        elseif ($flag -eq $true) {
            Write-Host `r`n"Enter valid Resource Group name"
        }
    }
```

For removing Topics use `Remove-AzureRmServiceBusTopic` you can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicebus/Remove-AzureRmServiceBusTopic?view=azurermps-6.7.0) and for removing Subscription you can use `Remove-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription` and there is docs available for that too [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicebus/Remove-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription?view=azurermps-6.7.0).

**Note :** Make sure you have AzureRm.ServiceBus module installed in the list of Modules, if you dont have then run this from Admin Powershell `Install-Module -Name AzureRM.ServiceBus`

Comment: @HariHaran...I am not using Azure Service Bus, instead I am using on-prem Windows Service Bus 1.1. Will these Azure version command will work?

Comment: I m using command `Remove-AzureRmServiceBusTopic -NamespaceName SB-Example1 -TopicName SB-Topic_exampl1`, it's is asking for `-ResourceGroup`. Now for on prem Service Bus I don't think we can pass any `ResourceGroup`, please suggest

Comment: Login to Azure, Select the subscription and Resource Group before you run this command and it should work. I've edited my answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: ahh! I m `NOT` using Azure, Thanks for your answer! I'm using Windows Service Bus 1.1

Comment: Even if you are using Windows ServiceBus , just login and select the subscription and use the cmdlet

Comment: where to login?

Comment: Before using the cmdlet, you must login and select the subscription programatically

Comment: In case of Azure, I can go to azure portal and can login and select subscription/resource, but where to login (what url, etc) in case of windows azure service bus?

Comment: you are doing the powershell commands from the powershell terminal right ?

Comment: Yes, through powershell only

Comment: yes then you can login->select subscription-> select Resoruce Group from the powershell code itself.